# True or false condition with same code using

Tags: c#

I have a simple `CheckedChange` event who check checkbox or uncheck it if one checkbox is checked or not:

```
private void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkAll.Checked)
            {
                chkByName.Checked = true;
                chkByDesign.Checked = true;
                chkByAddress.Checked = true;
                chkByCity.Checked = true;
                chkByZip.Checked = true;
                chkByContact.Checked = true;
                chkByCustomer.Checked = true;
                chkByJobNote.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chkByName.Checked = false;
                chkByDesign.Checked = false;
                chkByAddress.Checked = false;
                chkByCity.Checked = false;
                chkByZip.Checked = false;
                chkByContact.Checked = false;
                chkByCustomer.Checked = false;
                chkByJobNote.Checked = false;
            }
```

as you can see I have a lot of repeated code. I just changing true or false. There is no way to reduce code? There is another best practices to do that?

Comment: You could make a helper function that takes a bool ad applies it to each of the sub-checkboxes. I do not know if there is anything like a "checkbox group" that you can all check at once.

Comment: i think this question should be part of code review stack exchange- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `Checked` properties to `chkAll.Checked` directly:

```
chkByName.Checked = chkAll.Checked
chkByDesign.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByAddress.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByCity.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByZip.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByContact.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByCustomer.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
chkByJobNote.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
```

Comment: Or you could do it all in a single multi-assignment call

Comment: you could, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is adding all checkboxes that must be set into a collection that is initialized when the the form is created.

Then simply iterate through it and set the checked property accordingly;

```
//while initializing
chkCollection.Add(chkByName);
chkCollection.Add(chkByDesing);
...

private void chkAll_CheckedChanged(
    object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var chk in chkCollection)
        chk.Checked = checkAll.Checked;
}
```

If all the checkboxes in the form must be set then you can simply filter `myForm.Controls` and avoid creating a specific collection.

Answer (score 1):

In C# an assignment can be used as an expression yielding the assigned value itself:

```
chkByName.Checked =
chkByDesign.Checked =
chkByAddress.Checked =
chkByCity.Checked =
chkByZip.Checked =
chkByContact.Checked =
chkByCustomer.Checked =
chkByJobNote.Checked = chkAll.Checked;
```

I.e. in

```
x = a = b;
```

`a = b` yields `b`. Therefore the expression above is equivalent to:

```
x = (a = b);
```

and

```
x = a = b = c;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = (a = (b = c));
```

Comment: if you keep track of these in a list, you could use both strategies and do a foreach(var checkbox in checkboxlist) checkbox.checked = checkall.checked

Comment: This code is not very readable and I doubt it is 'best practice', well at least not in this respect